# Trouble Validating Hotjar Installation for Shopify app

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, hotjar

I successfully installed Hotjar using npm and the Hotjar script loads in my development environment. However, I'm facing issues validating it in the Hotjar panel. The challenge arises because it requires a specific URL, and providing any URL seems to cause issues. This is particularly challenging as the script is meant to run on various merchants.

[image]